# How can I show a "loading" image and some text until the webpage is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have a `<div>` element like below

```
<div id="dialog-box">
 <iframe id="Iframe"  src="http:\\blah.com" ></iframe>
</div>
```

How can I show a rotating image and some text like "opening shortly" until the `<iframe>` webpage opens in the `<div>`?

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve this you have to attach a `load` event handler to the iframe and also do not set the source of the iframe in the markup itself because before you attach the load event handler the event might get triggered.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kMu4z/4/)**. Instead of loading text you can replace it with spin image of your choice as a background or `img` tag.

**Mark up**

```
<div id="dialog-box">
 <iframe id="Iframe"  src="javascript:void(0);" ></iframe>
</div>
<div class="loading">
  <br /><br />
  <div>Loading...</div>
</div>
```

**Js**

```
function showLoading(){
  var $loading = $(".loading");
  var windowH = $(window).height();
  var windowW = $(window).width();

  $loading.css({
    position:"fixed",
    left: ((windowW - $loading.outerWidth())/2 + $(document).scrollLeft()),
    top: ((windowH - $loading.outerHeight())/2 + $(document).scrollTop())
  }).show();
}

function hideLoading(){
   $(".loading").hide();
}


    $(function(){
      showLoading();

      $("#Iframe").load(function(){
        hideLoading();
      }).attr("src", "http:\\blah.com");

    });
```

**Css**

```
.loading{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:#ccc;
    font-weight:bold;

}
.loading div{
    margin: auto 0px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: @saurabhranu - Did you take a look at this?

Comment: i am going to try it on monday...it's weekend ..no access to office computer from outside...

Comment: Which version of jQuery library are you using?

Comment: I tried to but then I saw a lot of UI things got broken... :( is there any turnaround for this

Comment: If you want to support IE9 then there is no way other than to upgrade jQuery

Comment: can u tell me in this code exatcly where IE9 is not compatible with jquery...then I would fnd out a turnaround...because there is always one...

Comment: There are many things broken with older version of jQuery in IE9 so I cannot point out exactly where it is in your code.

Comment: it's ur code man...try to run in IE 9 the demo u posted with jquery <1.5.2 ...dosen't works..

Comment: Can you debug and tell me where its broken? I can find a work around for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="dialog-box">
 <iframe onload="$('.loader').remove()" id="Iframe"  src="http:\\blah.com" ></iframe>
 <div class="loader">....your loading message here</div>
</div>
```

css (adjust accordingly to your requirements):

```
#dialog-box {
   position:relative
}

.loader {
   position:absolute;
   top:100px;
   width:300px;
   height:200px;
   left:100px
}
```

You can make some nice loading spinning GIFs to put in "loader" here: http://www.ajaxload.info/

Comment: And place an animated GIF in the div with class loader.

Comment: @Diodeus - What if `jQuery` is not yet loaded when iframe `load` event triggers?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this javascript library](http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/), you could be surprised. It uses no images and works in all major browsers (even IE6)